# Could not find stored procedure using ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server

**ConnectionString**
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=MLUserDB;Password=xxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;

[image]

I want to get procedure without MLUserDB schema include in the name of procedure and i'm trying to get the procedure by using ado.net...

I'm able to get the procedure with command text like MLUserDB.procedureName
but unable to get with command text like procedureName
I have created user with schema in MSSQL server as well

Comment: Take ADO.NET out of the mix. If you, as an admin, do `execute as user MLUserDB; exec sp_help 'procedureName'; revert;` in SSMS, do you see the expected results?

Comment: I'm unable to run the query until the default schema of the logged-in user is MLUserDB without adding schema with the table name.

Comment: I created a simple test on my local instance and cannot reproduce your issue. That is, I created a schema (mySchema), two tables (one each in the dbo and mySchema schemas), two procedures (ditto), and a user whose default schema is mySchema. If I execute as the mySchemaUser, I get the mySchema proc whereas if I execute as myself I get the one in dbo. Can you amend your question with a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: I have two databases, one is on my local machine, and the other one is configured by my client at Azure which is our live database. When I run my application using live database(Azure) credentials without passing any schema with command text it works, but with the local database it through the same above error, and when I pass schema with command text it works. I want to know what I have missed in my local database